# Question on application of Wilson's theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all positive integers n having the property that there exists a permutation $a_1, a_2, … , a_n$ of $0,1,2,…,n-1$ such that when divided
by n, the remainders of $a_1, a_1a_2, … ,a_1a_2⋯a_n$ are distinct.

I found this as a solved question in the magazine Mathematical Excalibur. I tried to read the solution but could understand only half of it. Any help to understand this problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the solution and tell us what you have already understood.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is this works if n is prime or if n=4 or n=1. The n=1 case is trivial.

Firstly, we need to have $a_n = 0$.

Otherwise $a_1,a_1a_2,...,a_1a_2...a_n$ will be 0 for multiple values and hence the remainder will be 0 for multiple values.

Wilson's theorem says

$(n-1)! \equiv -1 \mod n$,  if and only if n is prime.

As an extension to Wilson's theorem if n is not prime then $(n-1)! \equiv 0 \mod n$ except when n=4.

For the case of $n=4$, we get $3! \equiv 2 \mod 4$

When $n=4$
we can have our sequence as: $1, 1 * 3, 1 * 3 * 2, 1 * 3 * 2 * 0$ which is $1,3,6,0$

We check the remainders when dividing by 4, we get 1,3,2,0. All distinct.

But for any other composite number we're going to have a repeat of 0 as a remainder.

$a_1a_2..a_{n-1} = (n-1)!$ which when divided by n gives 0. And the same with $a_1a_2..a_{n}$ since $a_n=0$

Only thing left to show is that this works when n is prime.

$a_1a_2..a_{p-1} = (p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p$

The elements 1,2,... p-1 form a field mod p. This means we can do multiplication and division with them and still get an element in the set. Also every element has a multiplicative inverse.

We choose $a_1a_2..a_{p-2} \equiv -2 \mod p$

This means that:

$(-2)a_{p-1} \equiv -1 \mod p$

$a_{p-1} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \mod p$

This means that $a_{p-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of 2 mod p. We know this solution exists since we're in a field.

By the same reasoning:

We choose $a_1a_2..a_{p-3} \equiv -3 \mod p$

We choose $a_1a_2..a_{p-4} \equiv -4 \mod p$

etc.
until we get to

$a_1 \equiv -(p-1) \mod p \equiv 1 \mod p$

This way all the products have different remainders as required by the problem.

We solve for the other terms in the sequence just like we did for $a_{p-1}$

$a_{p-2} \equiv \frac{2}{3} \mod p$

$a_{p-3} \equiv \frac{3}{4} \mod p$

And we can keep going till we get to $a_2$

$a_2 \equiv \frac{p-2}{p-1} \mod p$

and we already have

$a_1 \equiv 1 \mod p$

We still need to show that all these fractions (1/2,2/3 etc...) are distinct mod p:

Suppose

$\frac{a}{a+1} \equiv \frac{b}{b+1} \mod p$

Then cross-multipling

$$ab+a \equiv ab+b \mod p$$
$$ a \equiv b \mod p$$

So they are distinct.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain that $a_1a_2....a_p-2$congruent - 2 mod p

Comment: We are choosing that product to be -2 mod p and solving for $a_{p-2}$. We want all our products to have different remainders. So they all have to be different mod p. So our first product is $-1 \mod p$ by Wilson's theorem. We choose our 2nd product to be $-2 \mod p$ and solve for $a_{p-2}$. We choose our 3rd product to be $-3 \mod p$ and solve for $a_{p-3}$ etc.

Comment: Oh ok i get it. If im not wrong you are making assumptions such that the case of the problem is solved. You are exploting the property that a new number is multiplied at each step. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Assume there exists a solution and solve. Since we CAN solve for the values, we know such a sequence exists.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115194/discussion-between-ameet-sharma-and-math-enthusiast).